# Prevent HtmlAgilityPack to select particular class

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I need to select all `tr` inside a table, actually for doing this I wrote this code:

```
 var tr = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");
```

this working good, but I need to skip the tr that have this class: `round-head expanded loaded`.

Is possible tell to `HtmlAgilityPack` to select all tr that doesn't have the class specified above? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the Xpath to check the value of an attribute:

```
//tr[@class != 'round-head expanded loaded']
```